# What's the equivalent of ISAPI TerminateExtension for an ASPX script?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll, isapi

My users call a legacy third-party DLL from a C# ASPX script, or from a VB ASPX script, or from an HTML form via an ISAPI extension DLL.

The legacy DLL has two entrypoints:  `Compute()` and `Close()`.  Once the DLL is loaded, `Compute()` can be called any number of times, but before the DLL is unloaded, `Close()` must be called to release various resources.  If `Close()` is called, the DLL must be unloaded and reloaded before calling `Compute()` again.

To minimize the impact on various resources, it is preferable for IIS to load the DLL once, handle all `Compute()` calls, and unload the DLL only when necessary.

The ISAPI extension knows when the DLL is loaded because IIS calls `DllMain()` and `GetExtensionVersion()`, and it knows when the DLL is about to be unloaded because `TerminateExtension()` gets called, so the extension calls `Close()` exactly as required.

The ISAPI form is simple because the extension DLL does all the work:

```
<html><head><title>Compute</title></head>
<body><h3>Compute</h3>
<form method="POST" action="CALLCOMPUTER.dll?find">
<p>
DLL input: <input size=30 name="inputField">
<p>
<input type="submit" value="Send to DLL">
</form></body></html>
```

The C# ASPX form (VB is similar) is:

```
<% @Page Language="C#" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.IO" %>
<% @Import Namespace="System.Runtime.InteropServices" %>

<script runat="server">
  public class DLLclass
  {
    [DllImport("COMPUTER.dll")]
    public static extern int Compute(string inputs, StringBuilder outputs);
  }

  private void SendToDLL(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(1000); // mutable string buffer for result
    int i = DLLclass.Compute(inputField.Value, sb); // fill sb with result, ignore i
    DLLresult.InnerHtml = sb.ToString(); // display the result below our form
  }
</script>

<html><head><title>Compute</title></head>
<body><h3>Compute</h3>
<form runat="server">
<p>
DLL input: <input runat="server" type="TEXT" size=30 id="inputField">
<p>
<input runat="server" type="submit" value="Send to DLL" OnServerClick="SendToDLL">
<hr>
<span runat="server" id="DLLresult"/>
</form></body></html>
```

When using ASPX, how and when and where can I be notified the DLL is about to be unloaded so I can call `Close()`?

If I put a `DLLclass.Close()` after every `DLLclass.Compute()`, then I also have to force the DLL to unload.  How do I do that in an IIS friendly way that makes sure the DLL is reloaded the next time the script executes?

Do I have to do `LoadLibrary()`/`FreeLibrary()` calls that somehow remain compatible with when IIS decides to load or unload the DLL?

Comment: The DLL is loaded into the process so will only be unloaded when the worker process servicing your domain is restarted or recycled, this is unpredictable & would not be something you would rely upon.  If you use FreeLibrary (twice) the DLL will unload but the next call to Compute() will fail because the marshaller is unaware that the library has gone away.  You could replace DllImport with a GetProcAddress approach and call the function "manually" but then you would need to take care not to unload the library whilst another request on another thread was not running Compute() concurrently.